# 32 Bit ODBC Driver Connection Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

Thanks for your time. I am new to SQL Server. I am using 32 bit odbc driver 17 and SQL server version is 2008. Using the same credentials, I am able to connect through SSMS but not through ODBC driver connection settings. I am not sure whats wrong on this one. Your help is highly appreciated.

> Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.04.0001
>
> Running connectivity tests...
>
> Attempting connection
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
>   TESTS FAILED!

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Strange since you are able to connect through SSMS.

But try to add the server name like this (with default port number): "ServerName,1433" (of course if the port for connection to the server is the default one)

I have seen this few times in the past where you are able to connect to the instance through SSMS without adding port number, and not able to connect with ODBC if the port number is not explicitly given.

Also it is very good idea to double check again all the connection details given such as - Username, Password, Default database to connect to.